# How to install and configure Maven on Macos

Tags: macos, maven

I am searching the best way to install and configure maven on Mac OS please?

Comment: Which part of this https://maven.apache.org/install.html is not working for you?

Answer (score 5):

There are two methods:

With brew installation:

- Install Xcode
- then launch this command on your terminal:
  ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
  You can continue then to install mvn by taping: 
  brew install maven

Without installing brew:

- Download the Maven, for example apache-maven-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz.
  Extracts it,
  tar -xvf apache-maven-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz
- Set Maven command in environment variable:
  Update ~/. bash_profile – create this file if doesn’t exist.

  ~/.bash_profile
  export M2_HOME=/Users/youusername/apache-maven-3.1.1
  export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
- Finally restart the terminal. Test it using:
  mvn -version

Comment: I strongly recommend to use the most recent Maven version which is 3.6.0 furthermore the `M2_HOME` variable is neither needed nor useful.

Comment: One other thought about. Best is to download Maven from the homepage and follow the instructions. For this is not needed to install Homebrew...